# how to group and concatenate

Tags: r

I have a data which I need to group on column ID and then concatenate the rows.

Current Data

```
ID   Name   Diagnosis    Medicine
1    A      a            a
1    A      b            a
1    A      c            b 
2    B      d            b
2    B      e            c
3    C      f            d
```

Result Expected

```
ID   Name   Diagnosis    Medicine
1    A      a|b|c         a|a|b
2    B      d|e           b|c
3    C      f             d
```

Code written till now is,

```
diagnoses<-read_xlsx("excel file.xlsx")
diagnoses <-diagnoses[,c( "ID" ,"Name" ,"Diagnosis" ,"Medicine"),] head(diagnoses)
aggregate(cbind(Diagnosis, Medicine)~ID, df, paste0, collapse = '|') write.xlsx(diagnoses, "Diagnoses.xlsx")
```

I have integer variables, bit variable, nvarchar variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `groupby` with `mutate`:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Name) %>% 
  summarize(Diagnosis = paste0(Diagnosis, collapse = "|"),
            Medicine = paste0(Medicine, collapse = "|"))
```

Output:

```
     ID Name  Diagnosis Medicine
  <int> <chr> <chr>     <chr>   
1     1 A     a|b|c     a|a|b   
2     2 B     d|e       b|c     
3     3 C     f         d
```

Comment: It is copying column names again and again. It is writing "ID" ,"Name" ,"Diagnosis" ,"Medicine"
"ID" ,"Name" ,"Diagnosis" ,"Medicine"
"ID" ,"Name" ,"Diagnosis" ,"Medicine"
"ID" ,"Name" ,"Diagnosis" ,"Medicine"
"ID" ,"Name" ,"Diagnosis" ,"Medicine"
"ID" ,"Name" ,"Diagnosis" ,"Medicine"

Comment: @paru80 Edited my answer, should work now!

Comment: @paru80 Does it work?

Comment: Editing worked. Thankyou Kindly

Answer (score 0):

If you read the data in `diagnoses` you should use the same variable in `aggregate` function in place of `df`. Another important thing is to save the output in a variable after running the function.

Try -

```
diagnoses<- readxl::read_xlsx("excel file.xlsx")
result <- aggregate(cbind(Diagnosis, Medicine)~ID, diagnoses,paste0, collapse = '|')
openxlsx::write.xlsx(result, "Diagnoses.xlsx")
```

Comment: Hi Ronak, Thankyou so much. It worked when i removed integer columns from the list. I have a columns where the value is same, it is repeating again and again. can i pick only one value from such column. so instead of 2|2|2 can i just pick 2 there or distinct values ?

Comment: Sure, you can use `result <- aggregate(cbind(Diagnosis, Medicine)~ID, diagnoses, function(x) paste0(unique(x), collapse = '|'))`